# MySQL pivot table and histogram at the same time

Tags: mysql, pivot

I currently have a table of the following form

```
account_id | phone_name
0          | samsung M360
12         | HTC One
58         | LG Optimus
12         | Novatel
.            .
.            .
.            .
```

and I want to transform it into a table in the following form

```
account_id | samsung M360 | HTC One | LG Optimus | Novatel | ...
0            1              0         0            0
12           0              1         0            1
58           0              0         1            0
.
.
.
```

i.e. I want to make a pivot table with counts of phone_names for each `account_id`.  The main problem is there are 50+ different phone names so I cannot do a MySQL pivot table in the usual way by listing each `phone_name`.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not have a PIVOT function but you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to convert the rows into columns.

If you have a limited number or `phone_name` values, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select account_id,
  sum(case when phone_name = 'samsung M360' then 1 else 0 end) SamsungM360,
  sum(case when phone_name = 'HTC One' then 1 else 0 end) HTCOne,
  sum(case when phone_name = 'LG Optimus' then 1 else 0 end) LGOptimus,
  sum(case when phone_name = 'Novatel' then 1 else 0 end) Novatel
from yt
group by account_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5144f/4).

But if the values are going to be unknown, then you will need to use a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN phone_name = ''',
      phone_name,
      ''' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS `',
      phone_name, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yt;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT account_id, ', @sql, ' 
            from yt
            group by account_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5144f/5). Both queries give the result:

```
| ACCOUNT_ID | SAMSUNG M360 | HTC ONE | LG OPTIMUS | NOVATEL |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|          0 |            1 |       0 |          0 |       0 |
|         12 |            0 |       1 |          0 |       1 |
|         58 |            0 |       0 |          1 |       0 |
```

Note: the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) has a default value of 1024 as the length of the string that is generated. As a result, you might need to alter the session setting on [`group_concat_max_length`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) if your string is too long.

Comment: I do know the phone names but there are too many to hard code.  I tried your second query but it did not return anything.  Is this because I am using MySQL no SQL?

Comment: @user1893354 This code is MySQL syntax. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: my apologies. It worked. My yt was actually a derived table and I forgot to substitute it in. It looks like it works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1893354 Ha, glad you got it figured out. :)

Comment: Now I have another question.  How do I join the result of this query to another query on account_id.  It doesn't seem to work like regular joins.